# How to set filename of your choice when you download file from shiny app

Tags: r, download, shiny

I have a simple shiny app which downloads a .txt file. My problem is that I want to be able to set the filename from the app and download it as filename.txt for example and not "download_button" as it is now.

```
library(shiny)

text=c("Line1", "Line2","Line3")

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    h4("Title"),
    p("Subtitle",
      br(),text[1],
      br(),text[2],
      br(),text[3]),

    downloadButton("download_button", label = "Download")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$download_button <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".txt", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      writeLines(paste(text, collapse = ", "), file)
      # write.table(paste(text,collapse=", "), file,col.names=FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: When you say "set the filename from the app", do you mean that you want to provide a text string in the app that becomes the file name? In your app currently, when I download the txt file, I am able to name it whatever I want, but the default name is given by: `paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".txt", sep = "")`. You're looking for different behaviour?

Comment: I use this put when I press download I take as name "download_button" instead of data.txt

Comment: Interesting. The default name I see when using your app as written is "data-2018-06-28.txt". I have no idea why that's happening, but see below for a fix that hopefully addresses the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this addresses your issue. I just included a text input with the default value set to your filename as above, and then set the filename in the download function to that text input.

```
text=c("Line1", "Line2","Line3")

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    h4("Title"),
    p("Subtitle",
      br(),text[1],
      br(),text[2],
      br(),text[3]),
    textInput("filename", "Input a name for the file", value = paste0("data-", Sys.Date(),".txt")),
    downloadButton("download_button", label = "Download")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$download_button <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      input$filename
    },
    content = function(file) {
      writeLines(paste(text, collapse = ", "), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: It is strange but i just figured out that it works when I open it in browser. Both the initial question and your solution.